# Omar Khayyam is well known as a mystical poet (Quatrains). He is also known as a mathematician. Are these the same?

Tags: mathematics-social-history, algebraic-geometry

Omar Khayyam is well known as a mystical poet (his famous Quatrains).

He is also somehow known as a mathematician (Equations of degree 3 ?).

Are these the same person? A colleague in Arithmetical and Algebraic Geometry says that we do not know. How much is that true?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayyam), he is a mathematician and a famous poet.Many of the books and magazines we read when we were students stated that Omar Khayyam (we say Ömer Hayyam) was a mathematician and poet. There is a great interest in his poems in our country (Turkiye). I also love his poems. For example; when I was young, I read an article about Omar Khayyam's mathematician and poet personality in a respected journal (Bilim ve Teknik) published under the roof of a state institution in our country.

It would be good to get the opinions of scientists from Iran and Turkiye, as they can examine Khayyam more closely.

**Some Additions:**

---

I found the relevant article in the magazine I mentioned in the [August 1998 issue](https://geomania.org/forum/index.php?topic=8157.0) . At that time, I was a curious teenager who had completed the third year of high school. The name of the author was given as Deniz Gündüz. He may be the person promoted in this [link](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/d.gunduz). (But I'm not sure about the link). I will try to translate some parts of Deniz Gündüz's article. Maybe if he sees this community page he can offer much better arguments on the subject. At the moment I think the poet and the mathematician person are the same. It will be happy to see the arguments of different views on the subject. I tried my best, but there may be errors in the translation. I hope that will be useful. Some part of the translation is as follows:

---

**Poet, Philosopher, Mathematician - Omer Khayyam**

Omar Khayyam was born in 1048 or 1044 in the city of Nishapur. (It is the first capital of the Seljuks, a Turkish state.) The word Khayyam is derived from a Persian word meaning tentmaker. This name may have been given due to the profession of his father or another family elder. After studying in Nishapur and Belh, Omer goes to Samarkand. It was here that Omer wrote his treatise on algebra, which has earned him a reputation to this day. Later, Omer Khayyam, who was called to the capital Merv by Sultan Celaleddin Melikşah, was appointed as the head of the scientists' committee established to create a new calendar. This calendar, known today as the Celali Calendar, gives an error of 1 day every 5000 years. The Gregorian calendar used today gives an error of 1 day in 3330 years.

The work that made Ömer Hayyam known in the Western world centuries later is Rubaiyat. One of the reasons why the Rubaiyat became so famous was that the translation by the great English poet Edward Fitzgerald was quite successful.

Omer Khayyam, who is so popular and famous in the literary world, is also well known in the scientific world. Khayyam, who had important works in medicine, physics, astronomy, algebra, geometry and higher mathematics, is said to "know all the knowledge of his time". His books, most of which are of scientific content, are:

1. Risale fi'l Barehin ala Mesailü'l-Cebr ve'l-Mukabele / on the Algebra and Geometry
2. Musahar fi'l Tabiiyat / A summary in the physical sciences
3. Muhtasar fi'l Vücud / Summary of information about the asset - The book is now in the British Museum.
4. El-Kevnn ve't-Teklif / Occurrence and Opinions
5. Mizan-ül-Hikem / Measure of Wisdom
6. Ravzat-ül-Ukul / Garden of Minds
7. Fi Şerh-i ma eşkel-i men Mosaderhate Ketab-e Oklides / This book is currently in the Netherlands.

Gerard Meerman was the first to mention Khayyam's work in the West. In the preface of his book "Speicmen Calculi Fluxionalis" he wrote in 1742, he mentioned the services of Islamic scholars to mathematics in a manuscript belonging to Omer Khayyam in the Leyden library. Meerman wrote that algebraic solutions of cubic equations were found in the work donated by Warner to the library.

F. Woepcke used this manuscript and two manuscripts in the National Museum of Paris when publishing his translation of L'algebre d'Omar Alhkayyami in 1851. A copy of the same book is in the Columbia University Library's collection of Professor David Eugene Smith. Found by Professor Smith in Lahore, India, this manuscript is essentially very similar to the Leyden copy.

...

Khayyam died between 1122-1131. Among the sources that give information about Khayyam, the most important one is his work called Çehar Megaale / Four Writings, written by his contemporary Nezami-ye Aruzi.

The author of this book, which is the oldest document about Khayyam, says the following while talking about famous people in the field of astronomy in the third part of the book: "I met Omer Khayyam 20 years before his death in Belh. He was a guest in the house of one of the notables living in the street of slave traders. Because I know his reputation, I followed him like a shadow to record a word of his. So I heard him say, '*My grave will be found where the north winds bloom every spring.*' Those words seemed absurd to me at the time, but I also knew that a man like him did not speak casually. 4 years after Khayyam's death Then I passed through Nishapur. Out of respect for a master of science, I went to visit his tomb. A guide took me there. His tomb was at the foot of the garden wall, the branches of peach and pear trees stretched out over the tomb, flowers spilled all over it. At that time, I remembered the words he said when he was in Belh and I cried."

References:

1. Ana Britannica, Vol. 17, pg 300.
2. Die Rubaijat Von Omar Khayyam, Sagdos, Milano
3. Dilgan H., Büyük Matematikçi Ömer Hayyam, Şirketi Mürettebiye Basımevi, Istanbul, 1959.
4. Kasıt D. S., The Algebra of Omer Khayyam, Columbia University, New York, 1972.
5. Meydan Larousse, Vol. 8, page 536.
6. Struik D. J., Kısa Matematik Tarihi, Sarmal Yayınevi, Istanbul, 1996.
7. Şardağ R., Bütün Yönleriyle Hayyam Rubaileri, Özgür Yayın Dağıtım, Istanbul.

Comment: The collegue who said to me we do not know if the poet and the mathematician are the same person is german, specialist in history of arithmetic and algebra. He is acquainted with iranian and turkish cultures.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really know. Unlike mathematics and astronomy, nothing of his poetry apparently survives in the original.

Wikipedia says:

"There are occasional quotes of verses attributed to Omar in texts attributed to authors of the 13th and 14th centuries, but these are of doubtful authenticity, so that skeptical scholars point out that the entire tradition may be pseudepigraphic.

and

" Edward Granville Browne (1906) notes the difficulty of disentangling authentic from spurious quatrains: "while it is certain that Khayyam wrote many quatrains, it is hardly possible, save in a few exceptional cases, to assert positively that he wrote any of those ascribed to him"